# Trying to remove left margin and padding from toolbar navigation icon duplicates the icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I've been trying to remove the margin on the left of the navigation icon of my toolbar:

[image: Icon with margin]

The only solution I've found so far that works for me is the following code I found in another SO answer:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) customView.getParent();
parent.setPadding(0,0,0,0);//for tab otherwise give space in tab
parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```

It works, but the result ends up duplicating the icon:

[image: Duplicated icon]

I've already tried setting the insets to 0dp. Here's the xml for the toolbar with this applied:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F6F5F5"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_mail_app_ico"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

For some reason, it won't apply the 0dp rule. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!